# Why React Router is showing 404 for routes

Tags: reactjs, apache, amazon-web-services, react-router, virtualhost

I just pointed my subdirectory to subdomain using virtual host as below.
all is going good. but when after getting sub.site.com/anyroute. when I refresh this url. It is showing 404 error. 
I don't know why this is showing.
anyone can help?
here is the virtual host code

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@site.com
    ServerName mysite.com
    ServerAlias subdomain.mysite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/subdomain 
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}` as a prop to your `<Router>` component in your React app.